Boolean times integer - anyone care to explain this gotcha?
I was surprised to realize that the result of multiplying a boolean by an integer depends on whether the boolean is a literal. A rare gotcha? It certainly got me.
Bonus points: where is this documented?
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 22 2023, 10:22:35) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> zz = 0
>>> not(zz)
True
>>> not(zz)*4
True
>>> True*4
4


not isn't a function... (not zz) * 4 is 4, just like True * 4; you're doing not (zz * 4).

In many languages false == 0 is unique and everything else is sort of true. Language semantics and priority of operators may determine how the result is displayed. ISTR at least one C implementation where true == -1 so would give "-4" as your final answer. "true" == 1 is more common though (less typing??).

@MartinBrown in Python, bool is a subclass of int so bool objects are integer objects.

not isn't a function. It's an operator, and it has lower precedence than *. So
not (zz) * 4

is evaluated as
not (zz * 4)

zz * 4 is 0 (because arithmetic between booleans and integers returns integers), then not converts this to a boolean and returns the inverse, which is True.
To get what you expected, use
(not zz) * 4


Take a look at operator precedence here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html
Multiplication

precedes boolean not

So
not(zz)*4

first multiplies zz with 4 and then negates the result. Since zz in your example was 0, zz * 4 is also 0 and not 0 is True.
If zz was something else, like 3, then zz * 4 would have been 12 and not 12 would have been False. So the expression was first computing the multiplication and then negated the result and getting a boolean end result.
On the other hand, True * 4 computes the multiplication between True and 4 and since multiplication is numeric arithmetical operation, it converts True to the most appropriate truey value, which is 1 and then multiplies it with 4, eventually getting 4 as a result.
In short:
Your first expression computed an arithmetic operation and then a boolean operation ending up with a boolean result, whereas your second expression multiplied a boolean with a number and converted the boolean into a number to get the result of said multiplication.
